# Autocheck checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple checkboxes on my page and a "Select all" button.I want ,that when i press the select button, all elements on the page to be checked.This is the javascript code that i have tried:

```js
<script>
    function selectall() {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("ch").length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByName(ch[i]).checked = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here' is the html:

```html
<form action="analize.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="button" onclick="selectall()" value="SELECT ALL" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="a" align="MIDLE" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="b" align="MIDLE" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="c" align="MIDLE" />
</form>
```

But it don't work.What is the problem?

Comment: It is hugely more efficient to store the result of `document.getElementsByName` and re–use the returned collection, `document.getElementsByName(ch[i]).checked = true` gets it again on each iteration. Also, store the length. Because it's a live collection, the length must be read again on every iteration before being checked as it might change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` attribute of the target elements is `ch[]` not `ch`. Also `.getElementsByName(ch[i])`
should be `.getElementsByName('ch[]')[i]`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("ch[]").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName('ch[]')[i].checked = true;
}
```

You could also cache the `NodeList` which is more efficient than querying the DOM in each iteration:

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByName("ch[]");
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    nodeList[i].checked = true;
}
```

Comment: @sergiureznicencu: please mark the answer if it helped you. It would be easy to recognize the best answer.